# Why I can not repeat request with Mojo::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I create `$tx` object as:

```
my $tx =  $self->ua->build_tx( $method, ... );
```

Then request:

```
my $res =  $self->ua->start( $tx )->res;
```

I got right response, but when I want to repeat request I get error:

```
my $repeat =  $self->ua->start( $tx )->res;
Can't call method "stream" on an undefined value at /local/lib/perl5/Mojo/UserAgent.pm line 155.
```

Why I can not repeat request?

Comment: Just guessing, you'll probably need new `$tx` object. http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Transaction#is_finished

Answer (score 2):

Mojo ua tx is not reusable so create new one.

Comment: I better will build `req` object, then put it into `tx` and reuse that `req` if required. Looking into code `build_tx` do work with `req` so it is better to name it as `build_req`... it will be more handy